# Can I add chapter animations in Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I am writing a swift playgroundbook on my MacBook, and I was wondering if it is possible to add tutorial animations between chapters like Apple does in "Learn to Code".

Comment: The "Learn to Code" is just a playground and if you want to see what it's doing, just navigate through the source yourself. You can either do this in the Playground app on the iPad (hit "..." button, choose "Advanced" - "View Auxiliary Source Files") or drag and drop the playground to your Mac (e.g. via Finder - "iCloud Drive" - "Playgrounds" and option-drag the file from iCloud drive to your computer and then navigate the files in Xcode or whatever.

Comment: If you want help with a particular animation (I'm not sure precisely which you're talking about because I'm just seeing the standard page/chapter navigation of the playground page format), show us what you've tried in your playground, describe what animation you got and more precisely describe what animation you want. And, obviously, if you haven't already, make sure to watch [Introducing Playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/408/) which describes how to author playgrounds and the format of the multi-chapter books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create cutscene animations, make an HTML document and place it in Manifest.plist